# Using For Each loop with a Where Clause for XElement

Tags: vb.net, xelement

I am tring to write a for each loop that loops through the descendants of an xml doc but only the ones that satisfy a criteria.

I thought i would be able to do this with the where clause but i am having problems with this. It would be great if someone could let me know if this is actually possible or if there is another way i could do this.

I am coding in VB.Net My code so far is:

```
For Each Room In xmlDoc.Descendants("Rooms").Where((Room >= Room.Descendants    ("ReservationID").Value = 80154))

 Next
```

The xml that i would like to loop through is:

```
- <NewDataSet xmlns="">
- <Rooms diffgr:id="Rooms1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <ReservationID>80154</ReservationID> 
  <Ref /> 
  <ReservationDateTime>5/10/2010 1:35:27 p.m.</ReservationDateTime> 
  <IsCommissionableBooking>False</IsCommissionableBooking> 
  <RoomID>800010</RoomID>  
  <RoomNumber>Double</RoomNumber> 
  </Rooms>
- <Rooms diffgr:id="Rooms2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <ReservationID>80154</ReservationID> 
  <Ref /> 
  <ReservationDateTime>5/10/2010 1:35:27 p.m.</ReservationDateTime> 
  <IsCommissionableBooking>False</IsCommissionableBooking> 
  <RoomID>800009</RoomID> 
  <RoomNumber>Motel</RoomNumber> 
  </Rooms>
- <Rooms diffgr:id="Rooms3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
  <ReservationID>80151</ReservationID> 
  <Ref /> 
  <ReservationDateTime>5/10/2010 12:22:16 p.m.</ReservationDateTime> 
  <IsCommissionableBooking>False</IsCommissionableBooking> 
  <RoomID>800009</RoomID> 
  <RoomNumber>Motel</RoomNumber> 
</Rooms>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any `Rooms` if you don't specify the `Where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a C# lambda `=>` instead of the VB.NET `Function` syntax. Refer to [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) for more details on syntax.

Try this code instead:

```
Dim query = xml.Descendants("Rooms").Where(Function(r) r.Descendants("ReservationID").Value = 80154)
For Each room In query
    ' do something with room '
    Console.WriteLine("Room ID: " & room.Element("RoomID").Value)
Next
```